# Marginal posterior and prior are similar (and flat!)

Tags: bayesian, inference

I designed a Bayesian model and sampled the posterior using a MCMC algorithm. 
My problem is that the posterior marginal distribution of a given latent intermediate variable appears to be uniform just as the prior I assigned to it. In practice this variable is supposed to have a substential importance on the model. Moreover, the posteriors over the other variables sound in accordance with intuition and essentially monomodal.

I am a bit confused with that situation. How to interpret this result? Have I to change my model? Considering that the problematic variable is an auxiliary variable that is not interpreted after inference, can I satisfied myself from these results, or can it be interpret as a failure of the modelisation ?

Comment: We could help if you show the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the likelihood surface contains flat ridges related to the parameters of interest, the prior information has a substantial impact on the shape of the corresponding posterior distribution. In these cases, it is important to employ reasonable priors since they will basically drive the inference. Therefore, if the prior is flat, then the posterior is likely to be flat as well. Flat likelihoods appear in several contexts, in particular when the sample size is relatively small.

Some simple recommendations:

1. Simulate several data sets of the same size to check if you observe the same problem.
2. Increase the sample size to check if the posterior concentrates around the true values (This should happen due to the [Bernstein–von Mises theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%E2%80%93von_Mises_theorem)). If this does not happen, then the problem may come from the software.
3. Employ a very concentrated prior to check if the posterior also looks like the prior. This would *suggest* that the likelihood contains a flat ridge.
4. Double check your code.

Comment: I would also suggest to extend the bounds of prior distribution, if they are restricted in the algorithm. Maybe the MCMC chain is not allowed for that parameter to go into some important regions.

Comment: @Tomas Good point. In point $3.$ I would suggest the use of an appropriate untruncated prior.

Comment: Thanks, I check the four points. For a data set of realistic size, I observe that the prior and posterior are similar (regardless of the kind of prior I used). For more important data set, hopefully a nice gaussian bell is appearing. The fact is that the model is supposed to be used with realstic data set :). What I am supposed to do now?